# reading from file by .nextLine

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

Im getting the following error when i run my program. It runs through the first line in the file but when it goes back to the loop in the main method to process the second line this is what i get.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 
    at Popcorn.barGraphByLine(Popcorn.java:94)
    at Popcorn.main(Popcorn.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

My Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Popcorn
{

public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
{

printHeading(4, "Popcorn");

//This will call a method to validate a user input as a file name, then
//create a Scanner object to read from the FileReader object
String fileName = validatedFileName();
Scanner inFromFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("Test.txt"));

printBarGraphHeader();

while(inFromFile.hasNextLine())
{
  String thisLine = inFromFile.nextLine();
  barGraphByLine(thisLine);
}


inFromFile.close();
}

private static String validatedFileName()
{
Scanner keyboardIn = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Please enter a file name.");
String tryName = keyboardIn.next();
File createFile = new File(tryName);

while(!createFile.exists())
{
  System.out.print("The file name you entered is invalid, Please enter a
  vaild file name.");
  tryName = keyboardIn.next();
  createFile = new File(tryName);
} 
keyboardIn.close();
return tryName;
}

public static void printBarGraphHeader()
{
System.out.println("                     Popcorn Co-Op                   ");
System.out.println();
System.out.println("                             Production in Hundreds  ");
System.out.println("                             of Pint Jars per Acre   ");
System.out.println("Farm Name                       1   2   3   4   5   6");
System.out.println("                             ---|---|---|---|---|---|");
}


public static void barGraphByLine(String str)
{
String acresString = "";
String jarsString = "";

//This takes any spaces of one or more grouped together and replaces it
//with a single space.
str = str.replaceAll("\\s+" , " ");

//This takes the String str that is composed of the entire line from the file and splits it into two strings at the
//comma, since every name has a comma after it.
String[] splitStr = str.split(", ", 2);

String str1 = splitStr[0];
String str2 = splitStr[1];

String farmName = str1;

Scanner readStr2 = new Scanner(str2);

while(readStr2.hasNext())
{

  acresString = readStr2.next();

  jarsString = readStr2.next();

}

double acres = Double.parseDouble(acresString);
double jars = Double.parseDouble(jarsString);
double jarsPerAcre = jars/acres;

String graphStars = "";
if(jarsPerAcre < 400)
{
  for(int count = 25; count < jarsPerAcre; count += 25)
  {
    graphStars += "*";
  }
  for(int count = 375; count >jarsPerAcre;count -= 25)
  {
    graphStars = graphStars + " ";
  }
  graphStars = graphStars + "|";
}
else
{
  for(int count = 25; count < 400; count += 25)
  {
    graphStars += "*";
  }
  graphStars += "#";
  for(int count = 400; count < jarsPerAcre; count += 25)
  {
    graphStars += "*";
  }
}


int afterNameSpaceCount = 29 - farmName.length();
for(int count = 0; count < afterNameSpaceCount; count++)
{
  farmName = farmName + " ";
}

System.out.println(farmName + graphStars);

readStr2.close();
}  
}
```

Comment: `String str1 = splitStr[0]; String str2 = splitStr[1];` it must be there - is your splitting regex ok?

Comment: The data is always going to be something to the effect:

Some Farm Name,         #ofacres               #ofjars    (with random amounts of spaces in between)

which is why i know it will only split into two with only one comma per line.

Comment: so is it possible, that there is no space after comma?
put `System.out.println(table.lenght)`, print variables - it will help you to find the answer :)

Comment: I think the error is because the main reads a full line from the text that contains a string in the format: some farm Name,  123  456.  

It then sends that string to a method that splits it at the comma, makes the first part a string, then parses the second one into a string that I use a scanner object to read to get each number out into a seperate string (each is parsed into a double). I thought since I have read that entire string by the end of that methd, when it returns to the main and assigns the next line of the file to the string to pass into the other method, that it would be fine.

Comment: @rzysia I am using test data that i know is in the format given, with name and numbers present. I havent yet added validation or any code to deal with if there is missing data such as no numbers, or negative numbers. Which now that i think about it, i have no idea how i will handle such errors in the text file...

Comment: so, for example, you can skpi lines where `str.split(", ", 2).lenght < 2`

Comment: I changed it to   
     str.split(",", 2)   
in case there will be no space after the comma and then trim the second part of the split after it is parsed into a String,in case there was space after the comma. Would that fix that issue?

Comment: I don't know - it looks like there is line wihtout comma - Exception message says that index 1 is too big, so array is with only one element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at these lines:

```
while (readStr2.hasNext()) {
  acresString = readStr2.next();
  jarsString = readStr2.next();
}
```

Here you are invoking `next()` method two time and there is no explicit check with `hasNext()` for the second call. You are at risk of `NoSuchElementException` It's not related directly to your problem, but it will the next that you'll find.

If you want to read two strings, you'll have to call `hasNext()` each time. But, pay attention: with your code, if the while statement loops for more than 2 time, you'll lost some values read from `readStr2`.

Comment: I thought that was what the hasNext was for as the loop condition?  Or are you saying if it reaches the end of the line on acresString then it will throw an error because there is no next for jarsString?

Comment: Yes, it was what I was trying to say: if you reach the end of file with the first `next()` call, the second one will cause a `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: so how would I remedy that? would I use an if statement to test if     .hasNext()   for each variable?

Comment: I have changed my code to:  

    if(readStr2.hasNext())
    {
      acresString = readStr2.next();
    }
    if(readStr2.hasNext())
    {
      jarsString = readStr2.next();
    }

that should remedy that issue, correct?

Comment: I suppose it should. Try it and let us know! And, if you could, please check the answer as **accepted** :)

Comment: Yes it works by using if statements, however now i have to deal with if there are negative numbers or no numbers, but thats a whole new problem i have to start working on myself. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem, my Test.txt file had a blank line in between the lines of data. So the second string, consisting of a blank line, that was sent to the method caused the error.